# Type Narrowing on interface Properties (removing null option)

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that has a property that can be null.
I want to check that's it's not null and then pass the object into a typesafe object

it appears that narrowing works when assigning the property to a variable
but when try to use the object as a whole, it can't work out that it can't be null.

I don't want to use casting as that defeats the point of design time type checking.

```
interface Person
{
  midddle:string | null
}

interface MiddleNamePerson
{
  midddle:string
}

function DoWork(person:Person) {
  if(person.midddle)
  {
    const middleName:string = person.midddle; // works
    const middle : MiddleNamePerson = person // Error: Type of 'Person' not Assignable to 'MiddleNamePerson' 
    DoStuff(person) // Error: the argument of 'Person' is not Assignable to parameter
  }

}

function DoStuff(value:{midddle:string}) {}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution**

Replace this simple check:

```
if(person.midddle)
```

with a better type guard:

```
if(hasDefined(person, ['midddle']) {
```

Such a type guard can be defined as:

```
const hasDefined = <T, K extends keyof T>(argument: T | Defined<T, K>, keys: K[]): argument is Defined<T, K> =>
  keys.every(key => argument[key] != null)

type Defined<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  [P in K]-?: Exclude<T[P], undefined | null>
}
```

**Explanation**

Control flow doesn't work upstream in TypeScript. By checking `if(person.midddle)` we know the middle name is truthy, but the definition for `Person` remains unaffected. It's still an object in which the property called `middle` can be `null`.

By changing the type guard in a way that it validates not a single field, but the entire object, we make sure `person` is a well-defined `Person` within the entire block of code.

Comment: Where does `Exclude` come from?

Comment: @Zarepheth from the standard library. It's been in TypeScript since version 2.8 I think.

Comment: That might be my problem, I'm still on 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript currently doesn't do this kind of widening based on control flow analysis (as far as I know).
It might be a good feature to add.

For now, while a bit involving, you can use typeguard.

```
function hasMidddle(person: Person): person is { midddle: string } {
  return !!person.midddle // btw your check will pass with empty string too.
}

function DoWork(person: Person) {
  if (hasMidddle(person)) {
    const middleName: string = person.midddle;
    const middle: MiddleNamePerson = person
    DoStuff(person)
  }
}
```

If you want to make the typeguard a bit nicer, you can use the `ExcludePropType` from `type-plus`:

```
function hasMidddle(person: Person): person is ExcludePropType<Person, null> {
  return !!person.midddle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty solution would be to just say I know this is the correct type and just cast it to the target interface.

```
const middle : MiddleNamePerson = person as MiddleNamePerson;
```

The recommended solution is to use a [Type Guard](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). Then the type will be automatically recognized as the narrowed type after using it. Here is the code using a type guard:

```
export interface Person {
  midddle: string | null;
}

export interface MiddleNamePerson {
  midddle: string;
}

// type guard function
function isMiddleNamePerson(person: Person): person is MiddleNamePerson {
  return person != null && person.midddle != null;
}

export function DoWork(person: Person) {
  if (isMiddleNamePerson(person)) {
    DoStuff(person); // person is automaticaly recognized as MiddleNamePerson becuse of the type guard
  }

}

function DoStuff(value: {midddle: string}) { }
```